# A good way to model sequenced value transitions in Haskell using types?

Tags: haskell

Say I have a hypothetical type called `Report` that looks like this:

```
data Report = Report {
    juniorReview :: Maybe (Person, Bool)
  , seniorReview :: Maybe (Person, Bool)
  ... many other fields
  }
```

and simplified functions like:

```
addJuniorReview :: Report -> (Person, Bool) -> Report

addSeniorReview :: Report -> (Person, Bool) -> Report
```

A `Report` must go through an sequence where a junior reviewer is attached and approves or not (the Bool in the tuple) and then a senior reviewer does the same. It must always go through the sequence in this order. But the type system does not enforce this. I would like it to. What's the best approach for this? I'm open to redesigning the data type as well.

Assume also that there are many other steps that `Report` must go through to reach its completed state, with each step adding more bits of data to its fields. I would like a solution that is easy to extend to a multi-stage process with many steps.

*edit*

Another requirement is that the value must be Show'able in every intermediate state. The intermediate states can't be an incomplete constructor like `(Person,Bool) -> Report`.

Comment: "In the end", yes, but please see my edit.

Comment: @CarstenKönig Yes, I thought of separate types and sum types, but it seems to be unmanageable when you have a huge number of steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current type has a fundamental mismatch with your domain: it can represent invalid states. Particularly, we can have various combinations of `Nothing` that don't make sense:

```
Report Nothing Nothing
Report Nothing (Person, True)
```

A good solution to this problem would be to replace the model of a report with a type (or, more likely, multiple types) that preclude invalid states like this.

This particular case is pretty simple, with a finite number of different things in your sequence. I would just model both directly as two separate types:

```
data Report = Report { ... many other fields ... }

data JuniorReport = JuniorReport (Person, Bool) Report

data SeniorReport = SeniorReport (Person, Bool) JuniorReport
```

Then your functions would look something like this:

```
addJuniorReport :: Report -> (Person, Bool) -> JuniorReport
addSeniorReport :: JuniorReport -> (Person, Bool) -> SeniorReport
```

If your whole process is not too complex or dynamic, extending this sort of approach to explicitly encoding it in your types is reasonable.

A more flexible and concise but slightly more difficult approach would be to encode the current stage of your process as a **phantom type** on `Report`. A phantom type is a type parameter that is not used in the type itself, letting you add arbitrary additional constraints to your types. It could look like this:

```
data Report stage = Report { ... }

data JuniorReview
data SeniorReview
...

addJuniorReview :: Report () -> (Person, Bool) -> Report JuniorReview
addSeniorReview :: Report JuniorReview -> (Person, Bool) -> SeniorReview
```

The underlying report data structure is the same at each step, you've just added a type annotation about which step of the process it's on.

If you have a really large number of steps, you could use type-level symbols instead of empty data types for the annotation. This would let you use string literals at the type level to represent each step:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, KindSignatures #-}
import GHC.TypeLits

data Report (a :: Symbol) = Report {}

addJuniorReview :: Report "Start" -> Report "JuniorReview"
```

However, it still gives you a good level of bug prevention and self-documentation. Also, you could avoid most possible problems by keeping the report type abstract and not exporting the constructor, ensuring that it can only be created using functions from your module.

Comment: Looks like we both had the same idea but with slightly different implementations.  What benefits are there to using `TypeLits` over a simple sum type?  To me I would prefer having a finite set of data kinds possible, whereas `Symbol` lets you put arbitrary strings.  This might be great for extensibility, but it also introduces more room for problems.

Comment: @bheklilr: Right, it depends on how you want to organize the process and how flexible or extensible it needs to be.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `DataKinds` and a phantom type variable for this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs     #-}

data Report = Report deriving (Eq, Show)
data Person = Person deriving (Eq, Show)

data ReviewerType
    = New
    | Junior
    | Senior
    deriving (Eq, Show)

data Review :: ReviewerType -> * where
    Review :: Report -> Review rt

type NewReview = Review New
type ReviewedByJunior = Review Junior
type ReviewedBySenior = Review Senior

finishReview :: ReviewedBySenior -> Report
finishReview (Review report) = report

addJuniorReview :: Review New -> (Person, Bool) -> ReviewedByJunior
addJuniorReview (Review report) (person, b) = Review Report

addSeniorReview :: ReviewedByJunior -> (Person, Bool) -> ReviewedBySenior
addSeniorReview (Review report) (person, b) = Review Report

reviewChain :: Report -> (Person, Bool) -> (Person, Bool) -> Report
reviewChain report junior senior
    = finishReview
    $ flip addSeniorReview senior
    $ flip addJuniorReview junior
    $ Review report
```

If you want to be able to show it, just have something like

```
showReview :: Review a -> String
showReview (Review report) = show report
```

With this setup you can have any number of steps defined by `ReviewerType`, but you won't be able to construct a `Review Int` or anything like that, and you can very explicitly state what stage each function is allowed to take.  The downside to this approach is that you can restrict a function to accept 1 kind or all of them, there's no in-between (without additional boilerplate and ugliness).